# How to remove proxy from git I try, but still showing the error how to resolve it?

Tags: 14.04, proxy, git, github

My git is stuck whenever now I try pull,push or clone I remove the proxy but still no positive response from git.

**Last time I used this command for proxy:**

```
git config --global http.proxy 172.16.0.2:8080
```

**I try these commands:**

```
git config --global --unset http.proxy
git config --global --unset https.proxy
git config --global --unset core.gitproxy
```

but still getting this response when I clone the repository or want to pull or push!

```
badar:DSA Lab Tasks$ git clone https://github.com/badarshahzad/SEGP_Group10.git
Cloning into 'SEGP_Group10'...
fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/badarshahzad/SEGP_Group10.git/': Failed to connect to 172.16.0.2 port 8080: Connection timed ou
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After using these comands

```
git config --global --unset http.proxy
git config --global --unset https.proxy
git config --global --unset core.gitproxy
```

These two commands work for me after --unset the proxy

Answer (score 2):

Use this command to get the list of all proxy defined, and then use `--unset` to disable them.

```
git config --global -l
```

Unset with the following command

```
git config --global --unset http.proxy
```

Answer (score 0):

Target does not exist: You can see the ones that do [here.](https://github.com/badarshahzad?tab=repositories)

The server responded with a 404 error:

```
404 Not Found

The server has not found anything matching the Request-URI. No indication is given of whether the condition is temporary or permanent. The 410 (Gone) status code SHOULD be used if the server knows, through some internally configurable mechanism, that an old resource is permanently unavailable and has no forwarding address. This status code is commonly used when the server does not wish to reveal exactly why the request has been refused, or when no other response is applicable.
```

Source of 404 error meaning: https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html

Comment: this link lead to my GitHub profile! What do you mean?

Comment: Actually it links to the repositories page of that profile. Attempting to access 'https://github.com/badarshahzad/SEGP_Group10.git/' results in a 404 error. this means that object is not there (whether this is temporary or permanent is unknown) and has nothing to do with your proxy.

Comment: Most likely it's a private repository so it makes sense that you get a 404

Comment: @GerhardBurger Ok, but it's his repository. Feel free to write a better answer!

Answer (score 0):

you need to also delete the environment variables below:

**HTTPS_PROXY**=http://10.55.20.71:128
**HTTP_PROXY**=http://10.55.20.71:128